# Question about rendering axes

Tags: plotting

I have data points for a circle and would like to plot it with Mathematica.

```
ListPlot[a, PlotLabel -> "MeshPoints", AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}]
```

But the axes are not correct, the plot looks like an ellipse. How can I render my plot to get the axis scales equal so my plot looks like a circle, not like an ellipse.

This is my plot
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `AspectRatio->Automatic` option which "determines the ratio of height to width from the actual coordinate values in the plot."

```
a = Table[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi, .1}];

ListPlot[a, PlotLabel -> "MeshPoints", AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, AspectRatio->Automatic]
```

[image]